# Stop repetitive radio streaming android

Tags: android, internet-radio

I have a problem with my app. I have an app that streams radio stations. The stream starts when the user clicks on a item of the gridview. To stop the stream i made a button(stop) that appears when the stream starts. The problem appears when the user click many times the same item of the gridview because when click on stop button the stream don't stop, how can i solve that ?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private GridView grid;
private InterstitialAd interstitial, inter2;
private TextView name;
private ProgressBar bar;
private ImageView stop;
private RelativeLayout rela;
private RadioPlayerManager mRadioManager;
private String[] web = {
        "Radio RDS",
        "Rai 1 Radio",
        "Radio R101",
        "Radio RTL102.5",
        "Radio Virgin",
        "Radio RMC",
        "Radio Antenna1",
        "Radio 105",
        "Radio Milano",
        "Radio Onda Libera",
};
private int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
        R.drawable.playy,
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRadioManager = new RadioPlayerManager();
    rela = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    stop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rela.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    ads();
    listeners();
    firstRun();
    animations();
}

private void ads() {
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5426545253667840/9595287619");
    inter2 = new InterstitialAd(this);
    inter2.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5426545253667840/9595287619");
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    inter2.loadAd(adRequest1);
    inter2.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }

        public void onAdClosed() {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            // Load the interstitial ad again
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    });
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    }
}

private void firstRun() {
    boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
    if (firstrun) {
        new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Radio Italia") //set the Title text
                .setMessage("Ciao! " +
                        "Con Radio Italia puoi ascoltare la maggior parte delle radio italiane gratis, senza nessun costo." +
                        "Radio Italia ha al suo interno degli spot(ads) che aiutano lo sviluppatore a continuare il suo lavoro." +
                        "Se ti piace l'app non dimenticarti di darli 5 stele su Play Store. Grazie!")
                .setNeutralButton("OK!", null).show(); //Sets the button type
    }
    // Save the state with shared preferences
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
            .commit();
}

private void listeners() {
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            rela.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (position == 0) {

                mRadioManager.play("http://www.rds.it:8000/stream", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando RDS");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://icestreaming.rai.it/1.mp3", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando Rai 1");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://str30.creacast.com/r101a", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando R101");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://shoutcast.rtl.it:3010/stream/1/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando RTL102.5");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://shoutcast.unitedradio.it:1301/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando Virgin Radio");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://shoutcast.unitedradio.it:1103/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando RMC");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://s3.mediastreaming.it:7568/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando Antenna1");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://shoutcast.unitedradio.it:1101/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando Radio105");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://sh1.inmystream.info:8175/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando Radio Milano");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position == 9) {
                mRadioManager.play("http://s6.mediastreaming.it:9064/", mediaPlayerCallback);
                name.setText("Stai ascoltando Onda Libera");
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mRadioManager.stop();
            }
        }

        ;
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRadioManager.stop();
            rela.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            interstitial.show();

        }
    });
}

private void animations() {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.abc_fade_in);
            anim.setDuration(1500);
            name.setAnimation(anim);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.share:
                    shareIt();
                    break;
                case R.id.play:
                    gp();
                    break;
                case R.id.like:
                    fb();
                    break;
                case R.id.plus:
                    plus();

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void fb() {
            try {
                Intent fb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/315814045239841"));
                startActivity(fb);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent fb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/Denis-Projects-315814045239841/"));
                startActivity(fb);
            }
        }

        private void shareIt() {
            String shareBody = "Ascult cele mai tari posturi de manele cu aplicatia Radio manele 2016. Descarc-o si tu,e gratuit! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denisprojects.radiomanele2016";
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Radio manele 2016");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Distribuie"));
        }

        private void gp() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent gp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            gp.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=DenisProjects"));
            startActivity(gp);
        }

        private void plus() {
            Intent plus = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            plus.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/u/0/102131527060290623635"));
            startActivity(plus);
        }
private MediaPlayerCallback mediaPlayerCallback = new MediaPlayerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMetadata(String value){
    }
    @Override
    public void onError() { rela.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        name.setText("Errore!Scegli altra radio");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
    }
};
```

}

```
public class RadioPlayerManager {
private MultiPlayer mMultiPlayer;
private MediaPlayerCallback mCallback;
private static String TAG = RadioPlayerManager.class.getSimpleName();

public RadioPlayerManager() {
    try {
        java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory() {
            public java.net.URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Asking for stream handler for protocol: '" + protocol + "'");
                if ("icy".equals(protocol))
                    return new com.spoledge.aacdecoder.IcyURLStreamHandler();
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Cannot set the ICY URLStreamHandler - maybe already set ? - " + t);
    }
}


public void play(String url, MediaPlayerCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
        mMultiPlayer = new MultiPlayer(mPlayerCallback, MultiPlayer.DEFAULT_AUDIO_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS, MultiPlayer.DEFAULT_DECODE_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS);
        mMultiPlayer.playAsync(url);
        mCallback.onBuffering();
}

public void stop() {
    mMultiPlayer.stop();
}

private PlayerCallback mPlayerCallback = new PlayerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void playerStarted() {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCallback.onPlaying();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void playerPCMFeedBuffer(boolean b, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void playerStopped(int i) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCallback.onStopped();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void playerException(Throwable throwable) {
        mCallback.onError();
    }

    @Override
    public void playerMetadata(String key, final String value) {
        if ("StreamTitle".equals(key)) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mCallback.onMetadata(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void playerAudioTrackCreated(AudioTrack audioTrack) {

    }
    public boolean isPlaying(){
       mMultiPlayer.stop();
        return true;
    }
};
```

}

```
public interface MediaPlayerCallback {
void onMetadata(String value);
void onError();
void onBuffering();
void onPlaying();
void onStopped();
```

}

No one knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

it is better to not start playing if the selected gridview item is already playing. so you can store the value of playing gridview item and check it before you call mRadioManager.play("http://s6.mediastreaming.it:9064/", mediaPlayerCallback);

Comment: Can u be more explicit, i don't understand ... make an example

Comment: boolean isPlaying=false;
if (position == 0) {
  if(isPlaying){
                //do nothing
}else{
   playing=true;
    mRadioManager.play("http://s6.mediastreaming.it:9064/", mediaPlayerCallback);
}
            }
        };
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRadioManager.stop();
            playing=false;
            rela.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

Comment: Doesn't work ... When i click on the item the stream don't start.